# Silent SQL Server 2014 installation fails with Access Denied on tempfile

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Title basically describes it.

Things I've checked:

- verified the name of the user in the remote powershell session (to make sure things are executing with the permissions I expect them to)
- checked the permissions on the described file.  The expected user has full control of the file
- removed the .tmp file and rebooted.  Install still fails
- **RDP'd into the server as the user that Powershell is executing as.  I cracked open PowersheISE and ran the silent install command manually.  It installed flawlessly**.

I get the feeling this may be an issue with the way WinRM interacts with permissions, but that's just a complete guess.  I'm not really an IT person and I'm unsure where to go next to try and solve this issue.

Below I've included the command being used, the config file being used, and the detailed error log.  IF anyone has any suggestions or ideas please let me know.

Here is the command I'm using

```
'D:\Setup.exe' /ACTION="Install" /FEATURES=SQL,TOOLS,RS /INDICATEPROGRESS=False /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /CONFIGURATIONFILE="$configFilePath" /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms  /SAPWD="$saPwd" /Q
```

Here's the config file

```
;SQL Server 2014 Configuration File
[OPTIONS]

; Specifies a Setup work flow, like INSTALL, UNINSTALL, or UPGRADE. This is a required parameter. 

ACTION="Install"

; Use the /ENU parameter to install the English version of SQL Server on your localized Windows operating system. 

ENU="True"

; Parameter that controls the user interface behavior. Valid values are Normal for the full UI,AutoAdvance for a simplied UI, and EnableUIOnServerCore for bypassing Server Core setup GUI block. 

;UIMODE="Normal"

; Setup will not display any user interface. 

;QUIET="False"

; Setup will display progress only, without any user interaction. 

;QUIETSIMPLE="True"

; Specify whether SQL Server Setup should discover and include product updates. The valid values are True and False or 1 and 0. By default SQL Server Setup will include updates that are found. 

UpdateEnabled="False"

; Specify if errors can be reported to Microsoft to improve future SQL Server releases. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable this feature. 

ERRORREPORTING="False"

; If this parameter is provided, then this computer will use Microsoft Update to check for updates. 

USEMICROSOFTUPDATE="False"

; Specifies features to install, uninstall, or upgrade. The list of top-level features include SQL, AS, RS, IS, MDS, and Tools. The SQL feature will install the Database Engine, Replication, Full-Text, and Data Quality Services (DQS) server. The Tools feature will install Management Tools, Books online components, SQL Server Data Tools, and other shared components. 

FEATURES=SQLENGINE,FULLTEXT

; Specify the location where SQL Server Setup will obtain product updates. The valid values are "MU" to search Microsoft Update, a valid folder path, a relative path such as .\MyUpdates or a UNC share. By default SQL Server Setup will search Microsoft Update or a Windows Update service through the Window Server Update Services. 

UpdateSource="MU"

; Displays the command line parameters usage 

HELP="False"

; Specifies that the detailed Setup log should be piped to the console. 

INDICATEPROGRESS="True"

; Specifies that Setup should install into WOW64. This command line argument is not supported on an IA64 or a 32-bit system. 

X86="False"

; Specify the root installation directory for shared components.  This directory remains unchanged after shared components are already installed. 

INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify the root installation directory for the WOW64 shared components.  This directory remains unchanged after WOW64 shared components are already installed. 

INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify a default or named instance. MSSQLSERVER is the default instance for non-Express editions and SQLExpress for Express editions. This parameter is required when installing the SQL Server Database Engine (SQL), Analysis Services (AS), or Reporting Services (RS). 

INSTANCENAME="MSSQLSERVER"

; Specify that SQL Server feature usage data can be collected and sent to Microsoft. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable this feature. 

SQMREPORTING="False"

; Specify the Instance ID for the SQL Server features you have specified. SQL Server directory structure, registry structure, and service names will incorporate the instance ID of the SQL Server instance. 

INSTANCEID="MSSQLSERVER"

; Specify the installation directory. 

INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Agent account name 

AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT"

; Auto-start service after installation.  

AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; CM brick TCP communication port 

COMMFABRICPORT="0"

; How matrix will use private networks 

COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL="0"

; How inter brick communication will be protected 

COMMFABRICENCRYPTION="0"

; TCP port used by the CM brick 

MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT="0"

; Startup type for the SQL Server service. 

SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Level to enable FILESTREAM feature at (0, 1, 2 or 3). 

FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"

; Set to "1" to enable RANU for SQL Server Express. 

ENABLERANU="False"

; Specifies a Windows collation or an SQL collation to use for the Database Engine. 

SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

; Account for SQL Server service: Domain\User or system account. 

SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQLSERVER"

; Windows account(s) to provision as SQL Server system administrators. 

SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\Administrators"

; The default is Windows Authentication. Use "SQL" for Mixed Mode Authentication. 

SECURITYMODE="SQL"

; Default directory for the Database Engine backup files. 

SQLBACKUPDIR="C:\MSSQL\Backups"

; Default directory for the Database Engine user databases. 

SQLUSERDBDIR="C:\MSSQL\Data"

; Default directory for the Database Engine user database logs. 

SQLUSERDBLOGDIR="C:\MSSQL\Logs"

; Provision current user as a Database Engine system administrator for %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Express. 

ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="False"

; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the TCP/IP protocol. 

TCPENABLED="1"

; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the Named Pipes protocol. 

NPENABLED="0"

; Startup type for Browser Service. 

BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"

; Add description of input argument FTSVCACCOUNT 

FTSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher"
```

Here is the relevant part of the detailed log file

```
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp: Error: Action "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.FinalCalculateSettingsAction" threw an exception during execution.
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInfrastructureException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access is denied.
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Common.SqlSecureString.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteSerializable(IXmlSerializable serializable, String name, String ns, Boolean isNullable, Boolean wrapped)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAgentConfigurationPublic.Write6_AgentConfigurationPublic(String n, String ns, AgentConfigurationPublic o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAgentConfigurationPublic.Write7_AgentConfigurationPublic(Object o)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(Object objectToSerialize)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateSettings(IEnumerable`1 settingIds)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateAllSettings(Boolean chainerSettingOnly)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.FinalCalculateSettingsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp: Error: Action "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction" threw an exception during execution.
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInfrastructureException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access is denied.
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Common.SqlSecureString.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteSerializable(IXmlSerializable serializable, String name, String ns, Boolean isNullable, Boolean wrapped)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAgentConfigurationPublic.Write6_AgentConfigurationPublic(String n, String ns, AgentConfigurationPublic o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAgentConfigurationPublic.Write7_AgentConfigurationPublic(Object o)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(Object objectToSerialize)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateSettings(IEnumerable`1 settingIds)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateAllSettings(Boolean chainerSettingOnly)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.FinalCalculateSettingsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.Workflow.RunWorkflow(WorkflowObject workflowObject, HandleInternalException exceptionHandler)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp: Error: Action "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction" threw an exception during execution.
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInfrastructureException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access is denied.
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Common.SqlSecureString.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteSerializable(IXmlSerializable serializable, String name, String ns, Boolean isNullable, Boolean wrapped)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAgentConfigurationPublic.Write6_AgentConfigurationPublic(String n, String ns, AgentConfigurationPublic o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAgentConfigurationPublic.Write7_AgentConfigurationPublic(Object o)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(Object objectToSerialize)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateSettings(IEnumerable`1 settingIds)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateAllSettings(Boolean chainerSettingOnly)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.FinalCalculateSettingsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.Workflow.RunWorkflow(WorkflowObject workflowObject, HandleInternalException exceptionHandler)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.Workflow.RunWorkflow(WorkflowObject workflowObject, HandleInternalException exceptionHandler)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:30 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp: Received request to add the following file to Watson reporting: C:\Users\htadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp39AB.tmp
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp: Inner exceptions are being indented
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp: 
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp: Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInfrastructureException
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:     Message: 
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         There was an error generating the XML document.
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:     HResult : 0x84b10001
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         FacilityCode : 1201 (4b1)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:     Stack: 
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(Object objectToSerialize)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateSettings(IEnumerable`1 settingIds)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateAllSettings(Boolean chainerSettingOnly)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.FinalCalculateSettingsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:     Inner exception type: System.InvalidOperationException
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         Message: 
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:                 There was an error generating the XML document.
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         HResult : 0x80131509
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         Stack: 
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:                 at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:                 at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:         Inner exception type: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:             Message: 
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:                         Access is denied.
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:                         
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:             HResult : 0x80070005
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:             Stack: 
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:                         at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:                         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Common.SqlSecureString.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:                         at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteSerializable(IXmlSerializable serializable, String name, String ns, Boolean isNullable, Boolean wrapped)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:                         at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAgentConfigurationPublic.Write6_AgentConfigurationPublic(String n, String ns, AgentConfigurationPublic o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp:                         at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAgentConfigurationPublic.Write7_AgentConfigurationPublic(Object o)
(01) 2015-02-14 04:31:36 Slp: Watson Bucket 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who runs into something similar, what I ended up doing is programmatically writing a simple batch file to kick off the installer, creating a 'run once and delete' task, and then waiting for it to finish. I had admin privileges, so I just had the task run under the admin account and it ran just fine. silly and hacky, but it worked